# Возможна автоматическая сериaлизация объектов?

Tags: php, сериализация

index.php

```
session_start()
class Boo{
    public $pub=100;
}
$obj=new Boo;

$array=array("name"=>"fozi",189);
$types=serialize($array);
$obj_ser=serialize($obj);

$_SESSION['obj']=$obj_ser;
$_SESSION['arr']=$types;
```

**mother.php**

```
session_start();
class Boo{
    public $pub=100;
}
$obj=unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);
$arr=  unserialize($_SESSION['arr']);

echo $arr[0];
echo $obj->pub;
```

Читая документацию:

> Если приложение использует сессии и
> функцию session_register() для
> регистрации объектов, эти объекты
> сериализуются автоматически в конце
> исполнения каждой страницы PHP, и
> десериализуются автоматически в начале
> исполнения каждой из следующих
> страниц. Это означает, что эти объекты
> могут появиться на любой из страниц
> приложения, став однажды частью
> сессии. Тем не менее, функция
> session_register() удалена в PHP
> 5.4.0.

Я правильно понимаю что можно получить доступ к объектам без этой сериализации?Как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, если написать так:

```
$obj=new Boo;
session_register("obj");
```

Но эта функция устарела с 5.4.0.
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-register.php

Comment: дык они там-же пишут:

    $_SESSION['obj']=$obj; 

это нормально и не надо вытрепываться.

Comment: eicto вообще замечательно.Премного благодарен ReinRaus ♦,eicto.